# Как лучше написать SQL запрос для получения данных из столбца

Tags: sql, запрос, таблицы

Имеем три таблицы:

1. Users (Здесь у нас есть ID).
2. Workflow (Здесь есть WorkflowID, который сопоставлен с UserID из таблицы Users).
3. Package (Здесь также есть столбец WorkflowID, который сопоставлен со столбцом ZipFileName(который как раз и необходим)).

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне, зная UserID, получить сопоставленные данные из столбца ZipFileName, из таблицы Package с помощью SQL запроса.

Я пытался сделать следующее, но по какой-то причине SSMS показывает ошибки, и из-за них запрос не выполняется:

`SELECT ZipFileName
(SELECT WorkflowID
FROM Workflow w
WHERE w.UserID = 23 )
FROM Package p
WHERE w.WorkflowID = p.WorkflowID`

P.S. Сильно не пинайте пожалуйста

[image: Таблица 1] [image: Таблица 2] [image: Таблица 3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select p.ZipFileName from Users u 
join Workflow w on w.UserID = u.ID
join Package p on p.WorkflowID = w.ID
WHERE u.ID = 23
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @ordman Благодарю вас, всё работает как надо! 

Немного подправил запрос только: 

    ```SELECT p.ZipFileName FROM Users u 
JOIN Workflow w ON w.UserID = u.ID 
JOIN Package p ON p.WorkflowID = w.WorkflowID 
WHERE u.ID = 23```